# querySelector a variable class name in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some external data fetched to some buttons , and I want when I click on a button to auto scroll to it section.
this is what I did :

```
  const Target = (e) =>
       document.querySelector("."+ e.target.className).scrollIntoView({
         behavior: 'smooth' 
       });
  }
{sideBarData.article.document.data.sections.map((sec)=>
      (
        <button className={sec.section.document.data.section_title.text} onClick={Target}>{sec.section.document.data.section_title.text == "" ? "Intro" :sec.section.document.data.section_title.text}</button>
      )
      )}
```

Eventually when I click on a button I get an error of querySelector is empty !

Comment: maybe this problem can be simply solved with anchor links?

Comment: no I need to click on buttons to be able to auto scroll based on the clicked event

Answer (score -1):

Use useRef against querySelector. The querySelector works in the real DOM. The useRef creates references to the virtual DOM, and these reference the manifestation realized during rendering.

Some links here:
[W3School with example](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp)
[Official react documentation](https://hu.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: can you please provide a snippet for this case